# Replace [ with { and ] with } using AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I found that in coding I rarely use the square braces `[]` but use the curly braces `{}` often. On most keyboards, these are inputted using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>.

Now I tried to use AutoHotkey to remap these keys by using:

```
[::{{}
```

Adding `{}` is raw mode basically, but it didn't work. Next I tried

```
{[}::{{}
```

but that also didn't work.

Any help?

Comment: Darren, I've updated my answer. Let me know if there are any problems. :)

Answer (score 11):

Using curly brackets for raw key interpretation is only for the [Send](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) commands. So, to map <kbd>[</kbd> to <kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> to <kbd>}</kbd> you can use:

```
[::Send, {{}
]::Send, {}}
```

---

**Note:** Remapping a key with its <kbd>Shift</kbd> equivalent is troublesome, as most if not all keyboards send the same [scancode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scancode) each time, the only difference being the introduction of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key (which has its own scancode).

For example, pressing <kbd>[</kbd> on my keyboard sends the scancode `01A` and yields a `[`. Pressing <kbd>LShift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> sends the scancodes `02A` **and** `01A`, yielding a `{`.

---

### Update:

I have **successfully** overcome the scancode issue with some clever logic! Using the following format, you should be able to switch any key with its <kbd>Shift</kbd> pair. Key repetition should also work.

```
*$[::
    if (GetKeyState("Shift"))
        Send, {[}
    else
        Send, {{}  
    return

*$]::
    if (GetKeyState("Shift"))
        Send, {]}
    else
        Send, {}}
    return
```

Expanding on this idea, [@Bob](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4705719#4705719) wrote a more robust version of the script:

```
*$[::
    if (GetKeyState("Shift"))
        SendInput, {[ Down}
    else
        SendInput, {{ Down}
    return

*$]::
    if (GetKeyState("Shift"))
        SendInput, {] Down}
    else
        SendInput, {} Down}
    return

*$[ Up::
    if (GetKeyState("Shift"))
        SendInput, {[ Up}
    else
        SendInput, {{ Up}
    return

*$] Up::
    if (GetKeyState("Shift"))
        SendInput, {] Up}
    else
        SendInput, {} Up}
    return
```

Answer (score 3):

If I were presented the problem without seeing the answer above, I'd just add a few hotstrings per the example below.

```
:*?:[::
    SendInput, {Shift Down}`[{Shift up}
    return

:*?:]::
    SendInput, {Shift Down}`]{Shift Up}
    return

:*?:{::
    SendInput, `[
    return

:*?:}::
    SendInput, `]
    return
```

Comment: Well done. No need to reinvent the wheel, huh? :)

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is bad solution if you use any shortcuts with braces keys, because it broke them.
Shortcuts-compatible version here:

```
$[::Send {{ Down}
$[ Up::Send {{ Up}

+$[::Send {[ Down}
+$[ Up::Send {[ Up}

$]::Send {} Down}
$] Up::Send {} Up}

+$]::Send {] Down}
+$] Up::Send {] Up}
```

Actually, in programming languages round brackets are used twice as often as curly, so I offer this version:

```
#NoEnv
#NoTrayIcon
#SingleInstance force
#MaxHotkeysPerInterval 200

; Swap [] with ()
  [::Send {( Down}
  [ Up::Send {( Up}

  ]::Send {) Down}
  ] Up::Send {) Up}

  +9::Send {[ Down}
  +9 Up::Send {[ Up}

  +0::Send {] Down}
  +0 Up::Send {] Up}

; Swap " with '
   $'::Send "
  +$'::Send '
```