# Using Different Mappings for Uppercase and Lowercase of the Same Key

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying use AutoHotkey to map some key combinations in a way that respects upper and lowercase, but I cannot get it to work.  For example: I want:

AppsKey + L types "a"
AppsKey + Shift + L types "b"

My failed attempts:

A. Both combinations only give "b" ("+" appears to be the symbol for shift):

```
AppsKey & l::Send a
AppsKey & +l::Send b
```

B. Won't compile and gives a "invalid hotkey error":

```
AppsKey & l::Send a
AppsKey & Shift & l::Send b
```

C. Won't compile and gives a "duplicate hotkey error" (which makes sense as it appears the hotkey definitions are case insensitive):

```
AppsKey & l::Send a
AppsKey & L::Send b
```

Is this type of mapping possible in AutoHotkey?  What am I missing to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on my work on the question [Replace [ with { and ] with } using AutoHotkey](https://superuser.com/a/425881/100787), I would use the following logic:

```
AppsKey & l::
    if(GetKeyState("Shift"))
        SendInput, b
    else
        SendInput, a
    return
```